# Cartesian to Polar coordinate transformation in manim

Tags: python, animation, math, manim

How can I write a code that would show me this transformation, in the same format as the equation not like carrying it to the complex plain etc. because I want to play with it for other functions as well.

[image: Click to open formula]

I tried myself a little bit and came up with this code that might be useful howeever I couldn't work it out to give me polar coordinates.

```py
class Transformation(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        
        line = Line(start=np.array([0,0,0]),
    end=np.array([2,1,0]))
        
        function = lambda pos: np.dot(np.array(pos[0]*np.cos(pos[1]), pos[0]*np.sin(pos[1])), pos)

        self.add_transformable_mobject(line)

        self.apply_nonlinear_transformation(function, run_time=5)

        self.wait(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform cartesian coordinates to polar ones, you need this formula:

```
fi = numpy.arctan2(y, x)
r = numpy.hypot(y, x)
```

Comment: How can you interpret that in the code?

Comment: instead of y and x substitute your coordinates

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand how to do it, can you please write the code a whole with your suggestion?